# Using a method inside controller to validate inputs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to use a method inside my controller to help with validation (NOTE: I cannot use `DataAnnotations` in my situation). But I am getting the logic/code wrong.

I am using `[Serializable]` to handle steps in a wizard, so my controller actions will go Details > Confirm > Submit.  The controller actions take a serialized parameter in my controller which is pulled from a View Model (the `myData` below).

The validation method:

```
private bool DetailsValidation()
{
    bool validate = true;

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(myData.FirstName))
    {
        AddModelError("FirstName", T("Please specify a First Name."));
        validate = false;
    }

    if (!validate)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return ModelState.IsValid
}
```

Here are my three actions in the controller (Details > Confirm > Submit):

```
public ActionResult Details(string nextButton)
{
    if ((nextButton != null) && ModelState.IsValid)
        return RedirectToAction("Confirm");
    return View(myData);
}

public ActionResult Confirm(string backButton, string nextButton)
{
    if (backButton != null)
        return RedirectToAction("Details");
    else if ((nextButton != null) && ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // code to add to DB
        return RedirectToAction("Submitted");
    }
    else
        return View(myData);
}

public ActionResult Submitted()
{
    // code to send e-mail
    return View(myData);
}
```

In the past I did use `DataAnnotations` attributes like `[Required]` and the `ModelState` check would fire with no problem. But I cannot use that now, hence the method `DetailsValidation`.  However, if I apply that to the `Details` action thusly (or using an `HttpPost` or placing it before the `return` to the Confirm action):

```
public ActionResult Details(string nextButton)
{
    if (DetailsValidation())
    {
        if ((nextButton != null) && ModelState.IsValid)
            return RedirectToAction("Confirm");
    }
        return View(myData);
}
```

With the above code the model validation fires immediately upon page load (if I use `HttpPost` in a separate DetailsPOST action that doesn't happen).

Now, if I use `HttpPost` (a plain `Get` action which returns the view and then a separate `Post` action labeled DetailsPOST) I sort of get around this problem except that I create two new problems.

First, if I go through submission and reload the Details page to keep testing, it will re-populate the form with the prior inputs.

Second, if I use a radio button list, instead of being set at the actual radio button selected it gets set to the last radio button. Weird.

Any thoughts on how to get through this. I just don't know how to get the `DetailsValidation` to work (without using separate `HttpPost` actions). Otherwise, the only other thing I can think of is to do all the checks I have in `DetailsValidation` inside the controller action which will make for some spaghetti like code.

Thanks.

**FOLLOW UP QUESTION:**

Would it be appropriate to just remove `ModelState.IsValid` from the Action and replace it with my private validation method like this:

```
public ActionResult Details(string nextButton)
{
    if ((nextButton != null) && DetailsValidation())
        return RedirectToAction("Confirm");
    return View(myData);
}
```

I feel like I would be losing out on the benefits of `ModelState.IsValid`, or maybe like it's a "no-no".

Otherwise, would this work:

```
public ActionResult Details(string nextButton)
{
    if ((nextButton != null) && ModelState.IsValid)
        if DetailsValidation()
            return RedirectToAction("Confirm");
    return View(myData);
}
```

But that doesn't seem right.

Comment: I'm curious, why are you no longer able to use the DataAnnotations?  Is it because your model classes are being generated?

Comment: I am using Orchard CMS (not really the point of the question). Orchard allows for translations using a special `T` function. However, this function does not work with dynamics, so I cannot pull in, for example, a DataAnnotation attribute like `[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please specify a First Name")]` and translate it. It has to be done manually in order to be able to translate. So in my view I could use `@T("Whatever")` for translations (like for a `<label>`); but in my controller I would just use what you see in the first code snippet above `T("Please specify a First Name.")` for validation.

Comment: @asymptoticFault Forgot to link your name so you can see the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inherit class ValidationAttribute and override method IsValid.

Than you could handle all your logic with manipulation to ValidationContext object

Comment: They said they are NOT using DataAnnotations, i.e. validation attributes.

Comment: try to use filters of controller or action to validate ur request

Comment: @user1956570 Not sure how I would use a filter. I thought about doing the validation in the action, but then my action code gets too busy, which is why i thought of using a private method to make it look cleaner. That may, however (and unfortunately), be the only way to go. Unless you can provide an example of the filter?